# Drools workbench test scenarios

Tags: drools, rule-engine, drools-guvnor, kie

Two part question:

1. I need to setup test case where one bean/fact has collection of items - is it possible to do with workbench editor, I picked Guided list and for each item I was trying to do new Item('sku', 'name') .. but when it tries to compiled it it has can not find Item class.  Item class is imported.
2. After deploying artifact to execution server and testing rules with SOAP UI where I did not specify session in the  tag - it seems like by default execution server uses statefull session which affect subsequent rule executions.

I went to project properties created "stateless" session

ksession, default=yes, state=stateless, clock=realtime

Now however if I try to execute by test cases in the workbench I get:

Unable to complete your request. The following exception occurred: Cannot find a default KieSession.

Any ideas???